# Is there a way to get a BufWriter's buffer length?

Tags: rust

A `BufWriter` has a private field `buf` which is inaccessible. How can I know the size of the data currently contained in it?

Comment: Why do you want to know the amount of data in the buffer?

Comment: I actually had troubles flushing it, I just wondered if it was possible to check what is inside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot (check [the source to be sure](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.24.1/src/libstd/io/buffered.rs#L386-L557)). The inner `buf` is not exposed in any fashion, presumably to allow for the implementation to change without breaking compatibility.

---

Well, you *can*, but it's terrible and hacky. You can print the `BufWriter` with the debugging formatter:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::{self, BufWriter};

fn main() {
    let mut b = BufWriter::new(io::sink());
    b.write_all(b"hello, world").expect("Unable to write");
    println!("{:?}", b)
}
```

```
BufWriter { writer: Sink { .. }, buffer: 12/8192 }
```

Comment: So, logically, you could `format!("{:?}", b)` and parse the result... /terrible-ideas